# How to make div flexible around an image

Tags: jquery, image, html, slideshow

I need the #slideshow div to wrap around each image no matter what size the image is. I don't like the gaps on the images that are smaller in height. How do you make the div  change size according to image size? Note: the space around the image is actually part of the image so that it completely covers the image underneath it. Thanks.

http://www.margaretlawrence.com/mlgallery.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <title>
      Here and There Exhibit
    </title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content=
    "text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <style type="text/css">
/*<![CDATA[*/
    body,td,th {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #000000;
    background-color:#dddddd;
    }
    * body, html
    {
    height:100%;
    }
    * {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    }
    #main {
    <!--min-height:100%;
    height:auto !important;
    height:100%;-->
    background-color:#DDDDDD;
    width:800px;
    margin:0 auto;
    text-align:center;
    font-family:arial, san-serif, verdana;
    font-size:11pt;
    margin-top:40px;

    }
    #slideshow {
    position:relative;
    width:400px;
    height:400px;
    max-height:400px;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    border:thin #ddd solid;
    border-radius:3px;
    box-shadow:2px 2px 5px #333,-2px -2px 5px #333;
    -webkit-box-shadow:2px 2px 5px black,-2px -2px 5px black;
    -moz-box-shadow:2px 2px 5px black,-2px -2px 5px black; 


    }
    #slideshow img {
    z-index:8;
    opacity:0.0;
    width:400px; 
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;

    }

    #slideshow img.active {
    z-index:10;
    opacity:1.0;
    }
    #slideshow img.next {
    opacity:0.0;
    z-index:8;
    }
    #slideshow img.last-active {
    z-index:9;
    }
    #title {
    position:relative;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    font-style:italic;
    color:black;
    width:400px;
    margin:0 auto;
    text-align:center;
    }

    #nav {
    float:right;
    width:120px;
    text-align:left;
    position:relative;
    top:120px;
    left:-80px;

    }
    a:link {

    color:black;

    }
    a:visited {

    color:black
    }
    a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;

    }
    a:active {
    text-decoration: none;
    }
    .caps {
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align:center
    }
    #nav a {
    font-family:arial, san-serif, verdana;
    font-size:10pt;
    }
    #nav a:hover {
    color:white;
    text-decoration:none;
    }

    /*]]>*/
    </style><!--[if IE]>
<style type="text/css">
#slideshow {
 border:none;
 }
</style>
<![endif]-->

    <style type="text/css">
/*<![CDATA[*/
    table.c2 {margin-top:20px;}
    p.c1 {line-height:180%;}
    /*]]>*/
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type=
    "text/javascript">
</script><script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type=
"text/javascript">
</script><script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    function slideSwitch() {

    var $active = $('#slideshow img.active');


    if ($active.length == 0) $active = $('#slideshow img:last');
    var $next = $active.next().length ? $active.next() : $('#slideshow img:first');

    $active.addClass('last-active');
    var caption = $next.attr('title');
    $("#title").text(caption);
    $next.css({
    opacity: 0.0
    })
    .addClass('active').animate({
    opacity: 1.0
    }, 1000, function() {
    $active.removeClass('active last-active');
    });
    }

    $(function(){
    $("#title").text( $('#slideshow img.active').attr('title'));
    setInterval(slideSwitch, 5000); // then every 5 seconds 
    })

    //]]>
    </script>
    <div id="main">
      <h2>
        Here and There
      </h2><br />
      <p class="c1">
        Exhibition at Greenhut Gallery, Portland Maine, June 2013
      </p>
      <table width="800" class="c2">
        <tr>
          <td width="175">
            <img src="mltext.gif" width="175" alt="" />
          </td>
          <td></td>
          <td width="25">
            <img src="mlspacer.gif" alt="#########" />
          </td>
          <td width="400" height="400">
            <div id="slideshow">
              <img class="active" src="images/from_the_porch.jpg"
              alt="From the Porch" title=
              "From the Porch 36&quot;x 36&quot;" /> 
              <img src="images/awake_first.jpg" alt="Awake First"
              title="Awake First 20&quot;x 24&quot;" /> <img src=
              "images/evening_on_the_pond.jpg" alt=
              "Evening on the Pond" title=
              "Evening on the Pond 14&quot;x 14&quot;" /> <img src=
              "images/first_light.jpg" alt="First Light" title=
              "First Light 36&quot;x 36&quot;" /> <img src=
              "images/from_shore.jpg" alt="From Shore" title=
              "From Shore 36&quot;x 36&quot;" /> <img src=
              "images/heading_north.jpg" alt="Heading North" title=
              "Heading North 14&quot;x 14&quot;" /> <img src=
              "images/heading_south.jpg" alt="Heading South" title=
              "Heading South 14&quot;x 14&quot;" /> <img src=
              "images/in_the_valley.jpg" alt="In the Valley" title=
              "In the Valley 48&quot;x 48&quot;" /> <img src=
              "images/mid_day_on_the_pond.jpg" alt=
              "Mid Day on the Pond" title=
              "Mid Day on the Pond 24&quot;x 24&quot;" /> <img src=
              "images/morning_on_the_mill_pond.jpg" alt=
              "Morning on the Mill Pond" title=
              "Morning on the Mill Pond 24&quot;x 24&quot;" />
              <img src="images/night_walk.jpg" alt="Night Walk"
              title="Night Walk 18&quot;x 18&quot;" /> <img src=
              "images/on_the_bay.jpg" alt="On the Bay" title=
              "On the Bay 18&quot;x 18&quot;" /> <img src=
              "images/september_sky.jpg" alt="September Sky" title=
              "September Sky 24&quot;x 24&quot;" /> <img src=
              "images/the_skys_floor.jpg" alt="The Sky's Floor"
              title="The Sky's Floor 48&quot;x 48&quot;" />
              <img src="images/watching_the_tide.jpg" alt=
              "Watching the Tide" title=
              "Watching the Tide 20&quot;x 24&quot;" /> <img src=
              "images/after_the_rain_study.jpg" alt=
              "After the Rain Study" title=
              "After the Rain Study 10&quot;x 10&quot;" />
              <img src="images/first_light_study.jpg" alt=
              "First Light Study" title=
              "First Light Study 10&quot;x 10&quot;" /> <img src=
              "images/from_shore_study.jpg" alt="From Shore Study"
              title="From Shore Study 10&quot;x 10&quot;" />
              <img src="images/from_the_porch_study.jpg" alt=
              "From the Porch Study" title=
              "From the Porch Study 10&quot;x 10&quot;" />
              <img src="images/morning_study.jpg" alt=
              "Morning Study" title=
              "Morning Study 10&quot;x 10&quot;" /> <img src=
              "images/new_view_study.jpg" alt="New View Study"
              title="New View Study 10&quot;x 10&quot;" />
              <img src="images/night_walk_study.jpg" alt=
              "Night Walk Study" title=
              "Night Walk Study 10&quot;x 10&quot;" /> <img src=
              "images/on_the_bay_study.jpg" alt="On the Bay Study"
              title="On the Bay Study 10&quot;x 10&quot;" />
              <img src="images/pond1.jpg" alt="Pond 1" title=
              "Pond 1 10&quot;x 10&quot;" /> <img src=
              "images/pond2.jpg" alt="Pond 2" title=
              "Pond 2 10&quot;x 10&quot;" /> <img src=
              "images/pond3.jpg" alt="Pond 3" title=
              "Pond 3 10&quot;x 10&quot;" /> <img src=
              "images/pond4.jpg" alt="Pond 4" title=
              "Pond 4 10&quot;x 10&quot;" /> <img src=
              "images/rolling_in_study.jpg" alt="Rolling In Study"
              title="Rolling In Study 10&quot;x 10&quot;" />
              <img src="images/september_sky_study.jpg" alt=
              "September Sky Study" title=
              "September Sky Study 10&quot;x 10&quot;" /> <img src=
              "images/shoreline_study1.jpg" alt="Shoreline Study 1"
              title="Shoreline Study 1 10&quot;x 10&quot;" />
              <img src="images/shoreline_study2.jpg" alt=
              "Shoreline Study 2" title=
              "Shoreline Study 2 10&quot;x 10&quot;" />
            </div>
          </td>
          <td width="25">
            <img src="mlspacer.gif" alt="#########" />
          </td>
          <td width="25">
            <img src="mlspacer.gif" alt="#########" />
          </td>
          <td align="left" width="150">
            <a href="Lawrence1.html">past works</a><br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <!--<a href="mlbreath.html">past works</a><br /><br />-->
             <a href="mlgard1.html">works on paper</a><br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <a href="mlnot.html">paintings</a><br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <a href="mlresume.html">resumé</a><br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <a href="mlhome.html">home</a><br />
            <br />
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table><br />
      <div id="title"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't know the height and width of the images, you'll have to use jQuery:

```
$("#slideshow").height($next.height());
$("#slideshow").width($next.width());
```

Just add the above code to (preferably) the end of your `slideSwitch` function.

Comment: Thanks. That does make the div change with the image, but you still see the bottom of the image before it. How do we make that disappear?

Comment: Just add `overflow: hidden` to the CSS on the div.

Comment: that works but the transition is choppy. any way to smooth that out?

Comment: Which transition? The fading one or the resizing?

Comment: resizing. it happens after the image appears so the next image is truncated for a second until the div resizes again

Comment: I think the div needs to change at the same time as the title

Comment: I can specify height and width of images if that makes it easier

Comment: You can animate the transition as well: `$("#slideshow").animate({ height: $next.height()}, 1000);`

Comment: looks cool with the animation, not so much when going from larger to smaller image. I think if the resizing can happen before the image changes, if i can put the code to resize where the title changes that would work

Comment: You can look into using `.delay` to delay the other transitions if that's what you want.

Comment: So I put the animated resize code right after the declaration for the $next variable and something cool happens. The resize happens at the same time as the slide change. Only problem is that in Safari, the resize animation slows down the slide transition and makes it very choppy. I'm thinking that maybe I'll make a conditional statement so that if the browser is Safari, the window resizes without the animation. Unless there is an easier solution?

Comment: If it's just a browser problem with Safari, there's nothing you can really do about it... that should be the simplest solution.